# How to see current SVN branch in WebStorm?

Tags: svn, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 9.0 for Web development. I have checked out code from SVN (I usually use git) using WebStorm's built in tools. I cannot find any easy way to see what is the current branch of the project through WebStorm's UI.

Please help!

Comment: What about status bar? It shows it for Git. In any case: please try **SVNToolBox plugin** -- it does that and can do a lot of other things ( https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7321?pr=phpStorm ).

Comment: Yes, tried this and its working. Thanks! I still prefer native IDE way to know current branch though.

Comment: You sound like you are doing some IDE hacking / custom coding in order to get such info... Although overall you are correct, of course -- such basic info should really be available out of box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like IDE does not provide such rather basic info by default.

Please use **SVNToolBox plugin** -- it does that and can do few other things ([link to plugin page on JB Plugins site](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7321?pr=webStorm)).

Comment: It seems that there is no alternative to this.